# How to find out which admin has added which member in Telegram?

Tags: telegram

I am going to sell a series of packages in the Telegram group and I want to give a commission to every admin from whose side the customer came to the group.

Comment: No way yet, most you can do is ask to group members after you've been added, a kind person would speak up ! :) https://www.planetofreviews.com/how-to-know-who-added-you-in-a-group-on-telegram/ Check this